# Access useContext in a function getting error

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to access the context in a function like so

```
import React, {useEffect, useContext} from 'react';

import axios from "axios";
import {Context} from ./store'
import Post from '../Post/Post';


export const fetchBlog = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useContext(Context);
        axios.get('/posts.json')
            .then(response => {
                const postsData = response.data;
                dispatch({type: 'SET_POSTS', payload: postsData});
            })
   };
```

And I import it from another component and use it like so

```
class App extends PureComponent {
    componentDidMount() {
        fetchBlog();
    }
...
```

but I'm getting error says

> React Hook "useContext" is called in function" which is neither a
> React function component or a custom React

How can I fix?

Comment: Try just to change the name of your function by FetchBlog you need a capital letter but you will need to return something I guess

Comment: You are breaking Rules of Hooks. React hooks are only valid in functional components and other custom React hooks, and they cannot be called in loops, nested, or conditionally called. You can use a context consumer and pass `state` and `dispatch` to the `App` component as props.